# JavaScript Menu accordion

Tags: javascript, menu

I have a menu accordion but there is a problem,

i want only level1(**CAT1,2**) menu clickable next level2 menu (**SUBCAT1,2**) opened or closed **but i want** level3 **fixed** 
(if opened then open
if closed then close)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian div").click(function(){

        $("#accordian ul").slideUp();
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }

    })
})
```

[click here to see my javascript accordion demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AmirHome/L90tjopz/)

Comment: Its not clear what you want exactly. Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you just need to change this:

```
$("#accordian ul").slideUp();
```

To this:

```
$("#accordian > ul").slideUp();
```

You can take a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and [this](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to see the difference between 'child selector' and 'descendant selector'

Here is yout jsfiddle modified: https://jsfiddle.net/xw66mmdt/